# heap error using findContours() on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I get a head error when I debug my code. My error windows say:

> Debug assertion failed!
>   File: f:\dd\cvtools\crt_bld\self_x86\crc\src\dbgheap.c
>   Line: 1322.

I have tried to fix it changing my project settings: linking MFC as static library     or using MFC as shared DLL but any of this solve my problem.

I think that it is a problem of memory when I use the function `findContours();`

I use Visual Studio 2010 and opencv 2.4.9. I dont have any problem if I debug this on Vivado HLS.

EDIT: I have solved the problem by making a new proyect and configurating libraries from the beginning again. Sometimes is very difficult to Know what is wrong in your directories and libreries settings.Thank you a lot for your help Micka

```
 #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp""
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include "iostream"

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;


    /** @function main */
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
        Mat src = imread(argv[1], 1);

        // Mostrar la imagen original
        imshow("Original", src);

        Mat canny_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

        int thresh = 100;

        // Detectar los bordes con un umbral min = 100 y max = 200
        Canny(src, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2);

        // Mostrar los bordes detectados con Canny
        imshow("Bordes", canny_output);

        // Buscar los contornos de la imagen, se almacenan en contours
        findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

        // Mostrar la Imagen modificada por la funcion findContours
        imshow("Modificada", canny_output);

        // Dibujar los contornos encontrados
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
        for (size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
        {
         Scalar color = CV_RGB(0, 255, 0);
         drawContours(drawing, contours, (int)i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        }

        // Mostrar la imagen final
        imshow("Contours", drawing);
        waitKey(3000);
      return 0;
      }
```

Comment: are you linking the debug libraries to release build or vice versa?

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm not sure what do you mean. Do you want to say if I have configurated C++ library directories adding $(OPENCV_BUILD)\include and $(OPENCV_BUILD)\x86\vc10\lib?? Yes, I did.

Comment: are you building in "release" or in "debug" mode? what are the filenames in your linker settings? e.g. opencv_core249.lib or opencv_core249d.lib ?

Comment: I am building in debug mode. My linker settings are: opencv_core243d.lib
opencv_imgproc243.lib
opencv_highgui243d.lib
opencv_ml243d.lib
opencv_video243d.lib
opencv_features2d243d.lib
opencv_calib3d232d.lib
opencv_objdetect243d.lib
opencv_contrib243d.lib
opencv_legacy243d.lib
opencv_core249.dll

Comment: I get this three error message:'myNewOpenCV.exe': se cargó 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_core249d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'myNewOpenCV.exe': se cargó 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_highgui249d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'myNewOpenCV.exe': se cargó 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_imgproc249d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: But I can execute my code anyway. I only get the head error after return 0;

Comment: remove opencv_imgproc243.lib and add opencv_imgproc243d.lib to your linker settings (debug library). and remove the .dll.

Comment: those missing PDB file messages are no problem. Just take care that you don't use release libraries in debug mode (see my last comment)

Comment: and your .lib files mix different opencv versions? I see most 243 but one 232 and the 249 dll file. please check your opencv version and use the right files as input!

Comment: I have done but it dont work yet. I have changed all 243 to 249 too.

Comment: opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib

Comment: These are my linker settings now

Comment: any other libraries in your project? still heap corruption message?

Comment: Yes it keep getting the same error. I have seen this message: HEAP[myNewOpenCV.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00C80000, 029C0B88 ). Maybe it can give you a hint.

Comment: please add if(src.empty())return 0; after the imread line (and maybe print some error message).

Comment: No, it dont print any message. My code work fine, the only problem is when the execution finish(after return 0). It generate a breakpoint and print the error.